# onclick form submit not working with prettycheckable styled checkbox/radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few forms that have custom styled checkboxes and radio buttons, with prettycheckable (from http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ ).

I am trying to get it working like this so that it automatically submits the form when a checkbox or radio is checked/ticked.

```
<script type"text/javascript">
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script type"text/javascript">
$(":radio").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
</script>
```

but absolutely nothing happens when it's clicked. I am thinking it may be because the actual checkbox is replaced with a styled span by prettycheckable. How do I catch that "click" anyways?

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
<script type"text/javascript">
$(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
</script>
```

But it's also not working. I have a feeling I'm close but I'm not really good at jQuery ...

Someone seems to have had the same issue here:

https://github.com/arthurgouveia/prettyCheckable/issues/51

And the above worked for them ...maybe I have a small error somewhere?

ONE MORE UPDATE:

Here is a JSFiddle of the same markup I'm using :)

http://jsfiddle.net/MKChris/5y2Uz/

Comment: Without your HTML, how exactly did you expect us to help?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the prettycheckable source code - in case you're using it like they provide it on their homepage, the inputs (regardless if radiobox or checkbox) are styled `<a href="#"/>`. So you could try - given an id="test" as container for your form:

```
$("#test a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Update: As Fiddle was provided with actual markup, I've just udpated it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/5y2Uz/2/)
Just check the console, answer above is working for me. I've just added a class="test" for the div containing the form and added

```
$j(".test a").click(function() {
              console.log("click");
});
```

When you check with e.g. Firebug, you'll notice that the styled checkboxes are styled `<a href="#/>`

Comment: Unfortunately my forms aren't that way ...they're standard form HTML, not with "a href".

Comment: Not easy to guess not knowing the markup.. can you update your question with the markup of the form-elements or add a link with an example of a prettycheckable-form that's the way you're using it?

Answer (score 0):

Applying `prettyCheckable()` alters the html including hiding the checkbox and enclosing it in a div. The html looks something like

```
<div class="clearfix prettycheckbox labelleft  blue">
  <input type="checkbox" id="use_4" name="4" data-label="Hasbeens" value="1" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
  <label for="use_4">Hasbeens</label>
  <a href="#" class="checked "></a>
</div>
```

You need to handle the `click` event of the enclosing `div` and check the state of the `checkbox`

```
$('.prettycheckbox').click(function() {
  var cb = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  if (cb.is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  }
});
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y2Uz/3/)